# Default value of Python dictionaries .get method as *args

Tags: python

I'm writing a function with *args and **kwargs (see full code bellow). The idea is that if I only have 2 parameters I don't specify the key, if I have more, I specify it.

i.e. the two types of calls are:

1. **with 2 parameters**: `sample_fct ('a_name', 'a_date')`
2. **with >2 parameters**: `sample_fct (name='a_name', date='a_date', other_para='bla')`

Hence, to access the value of name and date, I thought about using the dict method `a_dict.get(key [,default_value])`:

```
name = kwargs.get('name', args[0])
date = kwargs.get('date', args[1])
```

However, when doing this with the 2nd type of call (then one with 2+ parameters), Python (v3.7) returns an index out of range error.

Why is Python wondering what the value of `args[0]` if the key 'name' does actually exist?

**Full code:**

```
def test_kwargs (*args, **kwargs):
    print(args)
    print(kwargs, '\n')

    print(kwargs.get('name', args[0]))
    print(kwargs.get('date', args[1]))

test_kwargs ('file bla', '2021-02-02') #1st type of call
print('\n')
test_kwargs (name='file bla', date='2021-02-02', other_para='something') #2nd type of call
```

Returns:

```
('file bla', '2021-02-02')
{} 

file bla
2021-02-02

()
{'name': 'file bla', 'date': '2021-02-02', 'other_para': 'something'} 

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Users/Clement/Downloads/test_kwargs.py", line 31, in <module>
    test_kwargs (name='file bla', date='2021-02-02', other_para='something') #2nd type of call

  File "/Users/Clement/Downloads/test_kwargs.py", line 27, in test_kwargs
    print(kwargs.get('file', args[0]))

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: In the function you have `kwargs.get('file', ...)` but shouldn't it be `'name'` instead of `'file'`?

Comment: Because the arguments are evaluated ***before*** the function's call. So even if `date` exists in `kwargs`, `args[1]` will still be evaluated

Comment: Anyway, it seems like `name` and `date` are required arguments to your function, so they should be explicit arguments. `*args` is used when you have an unknown number of arguments, but here you know you're expecting at least two so it should be better reflected in your signature

Comment: Lastly it seems like you want `other_para` to be a [keyword only argument](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/#:~:text=Keyword%2Donly%20arguments%20are%20not,therefore%20'required%20keyword'%20arguments.). So even `**kwargs` is not necessary, simply use `def test_kwargs (name, date, *, other_para=None):`

Comment: Both `*args` and `**kwargs` are usually used when you don't *care* what the arguments are, but only need to pass them on to another function.

Comment: @Tomerikoo The example may have been over simplified but the idea is that deepening on how the function it used it would include 6 other parameters (beside `name` and `date`) or none

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write the function as:

```
def sample_fct(name, date, **kwargs):
    print(name, date, kwargs)
    # ...

And both ways should work quite well ootb:

>>> sample_fct(5, 4)
5 4 {}
>>> sample_fct(5, 4, x=3)
5 4 {'x': 3}
>>> sample_fct(name=5, date=4, x=3)
5 4 {'x': 3}
>>> sample_fct(date=5, name=4, x=3)
4 5 {'x': 3}
>>> sample_fct(5, name=4, x=3)
```

`date` and `name` are always bound to the positional arguments, and this notation ensures that at least 2 arguments are passed, regardless of the manner (as positional or keyword args).
Also, any mixup of positional and keywords will fail:

```
>>> sample_fct(5, name=4, x=3)
TypeError: sample_fct() got multiple values for argument 'name'
```